# Virtual host for subdomain overriding default virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have two vhosts set up in Apache.  One default one to handle all requests, and one for a specific subdomain.  The www directory is set up as follows:

```
/var/www
/var/www/subdomain
```

The virtual host configs are as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www>
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
                Deny from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost subdomain>
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
        <Directory /var/www/subdomain>
                Options None  FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Right now I want anything to `subdomain.domain.com` to be served from `/var/www/subdomain` and any other request to be denied.  However when I visit domain.com, it serves `/var/www/subdomain`.

Appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks!

---

EDIT with extra info when running `apache2ctl -S`

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using XX.XXX.XXX.XX for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default:1)
         port 80 namevhost sub.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subdomain:1)
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain>
```

Don't do that, since it's giving that vhost priority over the existing one for whichever IP that resolved to.  It should be `<VirtualHost *:80>` matching your existing vhost.  The `ServerName` directive is where the 'name' of the vhost should go.

You also need a `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere, if you don't already have that.

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  One follow up question, I tried adding NameVirtualHost *:80 to httpd.conf and the actual vhost file in /sites-available/ but I keep getting an error that says no vhost configured for NameVirtualHost *:80 when I restart Apache.  Where should that line go?

Comment: @Choy That's strange - what file are your `<VirtualHost>` blocks configured in?  And what output do you get from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: After running that command I get "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)" followed by "*:80 is a NameVirtualHost" and then a default server pointing to /sites-enabled/default and two namevhost listings (for default and subdomain that I mentioned in the original post).  The <VirtualHost> blocks are configured in sites-enabled folder as two separate files (default and subdomain).

Comment: @Choy Can you edit your question with that output?  The spacing matters for whether things are working correctly.

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting.  I edited the the original post with the output.

Comment: Hmm.  Well there's most certainly virtual hosts configured on `*:80` - if that warning is the only problem that you're seeing, then you can probably ignore it safely.