# ssl in subdomain installed but content not showing

Tags: php, ssl, subdomain

We have a 3 Year Standard UCC SSL Certificate in Godaddy and I added 2 SAN - one in a different domain and 1 in a subdomain. The domain added is in https without a problem. I have completely installed the SSL in my subdomain but the content of the subdomain is showing `Error establishing a database connection`.

This should not happen because the content of the subdomain is just `index.php` with `hello world` inside.

I already asked Godaddy what should be done but they can't be of help. They said it has something to do with our hosting but we are using VPS and I only installed the SSL through the server.

My guess is that maybe it's not working because the main domain is not in `https://` because I always see the error: `Error establishing a database connection` in Wordpress but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

Here's the content of my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.example.com
<Directory /var/www/subdomain_directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin email@example.com
ServerName subdomain.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain_directory
<Directory /var/www/subdomain_directory>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/SSL/subdomain.example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/SSL/subdomain.example.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/SSL/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You are likely looking in the wrong place.... This is something wrong with your wordpress install

Comment: @Drifter104 but the subdomain has no wordpress installed. just `index.php` to see if it works

Comment: Are you running apache or nginx? Have you updated the site configs for ssl? Are they proxying to the right directory? Just because you only have index.php for the sub domain, it doesn't mean that is the file you are getting to to get that message

Comment: @Drifter104 apache. I have added the configs in its `conf`. I'll post the content above

Comment: Add all the site confs above because it might not actually be using the one that you think it is using

Comment: @Drifter104 I tried adding it in `000-default.conf` before but it did not work so I added it in `api2.example.com.conf` instead.

Comment: also dont forget to mask your real domain , just to avoid security concerns ..

Comment: change http to https https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204405334/how-can-i-change-the-domain-name-for-my-wordpress-site

Comment: @Aravinda the main domain is not using https. Only the subdomain.

Comment: you need to change site url using wp-admin. if it is not available , you have to open database and replace WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)  value from http to https. its wordpress config issue not a ssl issue..

Comment: @Aravinda no. it's different.

Comment: this folder path /var/www/example_com_https_api has been not in effect then. you can clearly understand when you see this https://api2.example.com/license.txt  for some reason its over written. that is why your index.php is not working.. "Error establishing a database connection" -- 100% nothing to do with your certificate. virtual directories issue i believe

Comment: @Aravinda how can this be done? Without http, it's working okay, though.

Comment: see my previous comment and also this has a clue https://serverfault.com/questions/435786/virtual-host-for-subdomain-overriding-default-virtual-host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this in my conf:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain_directory
```

So now it looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.example.com
<Directory /var/www/subdomain_directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin email@example.com
ServerName subdomain.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain_directory
<Directory /var/www/subdomain_directory>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/SSL/subdomain.example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/SSL/subdomain.example.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/SSL/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did this solve the problem? If not, this should be edited into the question, not posted as an answer.

Comment: @JennyD It did solve the problem. And thanks for the edit!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution!